# Ruby HTTP get call again site that requires an active session

Tags: ruby, session, authentication, cookies, get

I am trying to get the source for `https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/index-status?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=xxx` in order to get the index status number which for some reason is not exposed via the `webmasters v3` API.

Now I can't just do a `HTTParty.get(url)` call since that will just give me a redirect to the accounts login page (`https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?xxxxxx`). If i run `HTTParty.get(url, {follow_redirects: false})` I get a 302 error since the page cannot redirect me to Google's login page.

Basically the question is: is it possible to either take my existing logged in cookie and supply it to the script or have the script "log in" an then store the session cookie?

The latter part would basically consist of:

- Get call to `https://accounts.google.com`
- POST submit the login form
- Await a response, save cookie
- Use that session to go to the above search console URL

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. If you're having trouble with code also read "[mcve]". We need a better description of the problem. We need to have a better understanding of how you're doing this. Have you looked at using [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize)? It's designed to help navigate a site and can handle cookies for you.

Comment: Thank you. With Mechanize I was able to get my google session and scrape the site I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to [@the-tin-man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) for suggesting `mechanize`. For anyone else looking how to get a valid google session for whatever service you need:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
login_page = agent.get("https://accounts.google.com")
login_form1 = login_page.form
login_form1.Email = "your_google_email_here"
login_form2 = login_form1.click_button
login_form2.form.Passwd = "your_google_password"
login_form2.form.click_button
#at this point you have a valid google session so the next part is specific for my needs
search_console_page = agent.get("https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/index-status?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=xxx")
total_indexed = search_console_page.search("td.property div.primary").inner_html.gsub(',', '').to_i
```

Now I just have to figure out how to store that cookie somewhere permanently so I don't have to login every time I use it.

Comment: YAML is a good candidate format. Just store the information in a file relative to your source code. The [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) class is easy to use and comes with Ruby. There are lots of examples of using it on SO. A disk-based SQLite DB is a bit more secure if you want to keep prying eyes from easily seeing it. [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Getting+Started) makes that easy. You could encrypt it and decrypt it on the fly, if you're more paranoid, but if the source is available that'd be a waste of time.

Comment: If Google has an associated API for whatever you're trying to scrape, you're better off using it. Scraping is a last ditch attempt and more failure prone.

Comment: As I mentioned this particular datapoint is not part of the API so I have to resort to scraping. Thanks for the YAML tip I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use your cookie and send it. That's how browsers work.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

```
GET /spec.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: theme=light; sessionToken=abc123
…
```

It takes a bit of work to figure out exactly what is going on. I suggest looking at the Network tab on the browser to see each HTTP request.